# Is it possible to change the value of an annotation using ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

I am trying to develop a tool that needs to work with annotations.
One important feature is to target an element annotated with an annotation and change its value, i.e.

```java
// from this
@Annotation(value = "foo")
class SomeClass {}

// to this
@Annotation(value = "bar")
class SomeClass {}
```

I made an attempt in which first I remove the annotation with an `AsmVisitorWrapper` and then I re-add the annotation with the modified value.
Sadly this does not seem to work.

I used the byte-buddy-maven-plugin to add this transformation. The error happens during the transform goal. I tracked down the generic error to a `NullReferenceException`: the Asm ClassVisitor seems to take place after the `annotateType()` step and tries to apply some visit step to the new attached annotation value. I think the `NullReferenceException` is caused by the visitor beacuse to remove an annotation you need to return null.

I made a test repository on github where I pushed my attempt. Hoping it helps to understand what I need to achieve. https://github.com/Fed03/bytebuddy-switch-annotation-test

Thanks

Comment: Which part does not work? Does it not remove the annotation? Does it remove but not add the annotation?

Comment: @kutschkem updated the question with more details, but I think the code speaks for itself better then I could

Comment: `NullReferenceException` may happen in C#, in Java, it's `NullPointerException`. Anyway, it looks like you're wasting your time with trying to fix a problem with removing an annotation when you're actually do not want to remove the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug in Byte Buddy that is now fixed on master and will be part of version 1.10.2. The problem is that you are removing an annotation that you are adding and this was not considered as a scenario.

However, even with this fix, your problem is not solved despite a green build. You would need to discriminate better to tell Byte Buddy which annotation you are removing. I would recommend you to transform an annotation rather then removing it to later add it again. Any matcher that discriminates to which of the two annotations needs to be removed needs to partially implement such change discovery already which is why it should not be much more difficult to implement the transformer in the first place.

Comment: I think I found a better way, that is a simple asm annotation vistor that changes the value...sure it is sad that there is no built in way to do this. many thanks for the fix though

Comment: I agree that this is the easiest solution, most likely. I'll keep an eye on making this easier in the future.